# How to figure out who merged dev and master?

Tags: git, bitbucket

We have a git repo, which has DEV and MASTER branches. Typically, our workflow looks like this:

1. Checkout from MASTER
2. Branch out into our own branch (e.g. BRA123)
3. Commit our changes to BRA123
4. Merge BRA123 to DEV, see if all goes well
5. Merge BRA123 to MASTER

Now, every now and again someone makes a mistake (*something* happens), and our DEV commit history is showing up in MASTER, alongside all master history. Effectively, this tells me someone pulled from DEV and checked into MASTER (hint: I think it was me)

Question - how do I go about finding out who did this? Reversing it is a different question, but for starters I want to know where things went sour. I already owned up to the mistake (for the sake of getting bureaucracy out of the way), but it may not be my fault in which case I'm eager to clear myself of any wrongdoing.

Could someone please offer insight into the cause?

Additional Info: I just figured out that it was indeed my merge that caused the issue, but info associated with my branch shows nothing about it being pulled from DEV or containing any changes other than the ones I've made. Does anyone know how to undo this in the most elegant, non-invasive way? There were other commits/merges after mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `git log`? It provide quite a lot of  information on the workflow of your repository.

Here is an example of what it prints:

> Merge: 7c0a9c6 c11a427
>
> Author: Toto Titi
>
> Date:   Mon Sep 21 16:19:46 2015 +0200
>
> 'Commit message'

Look for a merge.

Comment: Yes, I looked through the logs, statuses, reflogs, GUI - as well as commit data (from GUI), and specific merger details (dev/master) are not present anywhere. Is there a way to find out which branch my current branch originated from? That would give me a good starting point.

Comment: That's the function of `log`. Maybe can you try print in graph and with different information. See [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History).  For example : `git log --pretty=format:"%h %an %s" --graph`. Then you can use [this kind of trick](http://christoph.ruegg.name/blog/git-howto-revert-a-commit-already-pushed-to-a-remote-reposit.html) to undo your work on master.